# angular then catch success error from services

Tags: angularjs, promise

I'm afraid I may have gone down the rabbit hole of recursive promises.

I have a service that handles my api. (It's got an extra layer of promise so that I could switch back to a local json if the api went offline. (Not sure how necessary it is anymore) - mayte I should eliminate it for simplicity).
Then I've got the promised async call in my controller.

This all works great as *long as I get the data I expect*, but it doesn't handle errors very well. When I get 400's and 500's, it doesn't send the error message to the user via toastr.

Sadly, this is not a fully-compliant RESTful api. The 400 error I get back is simply

```
{"Message":"No packages found"}
```

I don't really get how to get this to behave as it should, and replace success/error with then/catch (as per Angular best practice).

Here is a typical service call:

```
var _getPackagesPage = function (options) {

    var pageSize = options.data.pageSize;
    var page = options.data.page -1;
    return $q (function(resolve, reject) {
        switch (dataSource) {
            case 'api'://staging - live api data
                return $http({
                    method: 'get',
                    url: serviceBase + 'api/Packages?pageSize=' + pageSize + '&page=' + page
                }).then(function(results) {
                    resolve(results);
                });
                break;

            default: // dev - local json

                $.getJSON('Content/data/Packages.json', function (json) {
                    var pageSize = options.data.pageSize;
                    var page = options.data.page;
                    var newjson = json.splice(page*pageSize,pageSize);
                    resolve(newjson);
                });
        }
    });
};
```

and a typical call in a controller:

(**options** is the data object handed back to my data grid (Kendo))

```
    vm.getPackages = function(options) {
        return packagesService.getPackagesPage (options)
            .then(function(results) {
                options.success(results.data.Items);
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                options.error(error);
                toastr.error(error.Message);
            });
    };
```

How can I clean this up?

**[ UPDATE ] Attempted fix per Answer 1, below**

Service:

```
    var _getOrdersPage = function (options) {

        var deff = $q.defer();
        var pageSize = options.data.pageSize;
        var page = options.data.page -1;
        return $http({
            method: 'get',
            url: serviceBase + 'api/Packages?pageSize=' + pageSize + '&page=' + page
        })
        .then(
            function(results) {
                deff.resolve(results);
            },
            function(ex){ 
                deff.reject(ex);
            });
        return deff.promise;
    };
```

Controller:

```
    vm.getOrders = function (options) {
        return ordersService.getOrdersPage (options)
            .then(function(results) {
                console.log("results!");
                console.log(results);
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                console.log("error!");
                console.log(error);
            });
    };
```

results in:

> GET http://< myURL >/api/Packages?pageSize=20&page=0 400 (Bad Request)
>
> results!
>
> undefined

Comment: Clean what up? can you ask a single, simple question?

Comment: I wish I could. There's got to be a *correct* way of using a service and making an $http call and returning results/errors. This isn't it.

Comment: You can load jsons with `$http`. just saying...

Comment: Yes, avoid the [deferred antipattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572)!

Comment: I wish I understood promises well enough to recognize a *pattern*, let alone an *anti*-pattern, never mind splitting it across two modules.

Comment: @Muli: 'You can load jsons with $http'. But I *am* using an $http - in my service.

Comment: You're using $. Getjson too

Comment: There are an infinite number of ways of doing it wrong. Does anyone know how to do it right?

Answer (score 1):

I'm removing the switch case for brevity.

```
var _getPackagesPage = function (options) {

var pageSize = options.data.pageSize;
var page = options.data.page -1;
var deff = $q.defer();

$http({
      method: 'get',
      url: serviceBase + 'api/Packages?pageSize=' + pageSize + '&page=' + page
      }).then(
           function(results) {
              deff.resolve(results);
            },
            function(ex){ 
              deff.reject(ex);
             });

 return deff.promise;
    };
```

Controller

```
vm.getOrders = function (options) {
    return ordersService.getOrdersPage (options)
        .then(
         function(results) {
            console.log("results!");
            console.log(results);
        },
        function(error) {
            console.log("error!");
            console.log(error);
        });
};
```

If you dont have any logic inside your service, then you could return the $http itself as $http inturn is a promise:

```
var _getPackagesPage = function (options) {

  var pageSize = options.data.pageSize;
  var page = options.data.page -1;

   return $http({
        method: 'get',
         url: serviceBase + 'api/Packages?pageSize=' + pageSize + '&page=' + page
      });

    };
```

Comment: This seems to return a success to my controller, even though it's a 400. So options.success(results.data.Items) returns data = undefined.

Comment: When your service returns 400, that would come to the error call back of .then method from where we reject the promise. This will not reach your success call back in controller, this will hit the error callbacj instead.

Comment: And yet that is not what happens. I've added the attempted fix and the outcome, to the opening post.

Comment: Could you verify whether its hitting deff.reject(ex); in the service?

Comment: It is indeed hitting deff.reject. ex contains Status: 400, StatusMessage: "Bad Request".

Comment: Ah. That seems to do the trick. Now I find a message under error.StatusText

Comment: No. I spoke too soon. It is actually captured in .then(), not in catch().

Comment: @DaveC426913 - not sure why you specifically need that in catch block; that's what error callback is for. If you need this in catch block, then try throwing error instead of deff.reject(ex);

Comment: @DaveC426913 - check this fiddle: https://plnkr.co/edit/DuGLKhRmpnJH7yJzxpHQ?p=preview . Im getting the exception in catch block.

Answer (score 0):

You have too many returns in your service. The second one is not called.

You don't need to create a promise manually since $http returns apromise.

You're not returning data from your service.

```
var _getOrdersPage = function(options) {
        var pageSize = options.data.pageSize;
        var page = options.data.page -1;
        return $http({
            method: 'get',
            url: serviceBase + 'api/Packages?pageSize=' + pageSize + '&page=' + page
        })
        .then(
            function(results) {
                return results;
            },
            function(ex){
                return ex;
            });
}
```

Your controller is fine, you can use catch() or pass an error callback.

Example:

```js
function myService($http) {
  this.getData = function(url) {
    return $http.get(url).
    then(function(response) {
      return response.data;
    }, function(error) {
      return error;
    });
  }
};

function MyController(myService) {
  var vm = this;  
  vm.result = [];
  vm.apiUrl = "https://randomuser.me/api/";
  myService.getData(vm.apiUrl).then(function (data) {
    vm.result = data;
  },
  function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
};

angular.module('myApp', []);
angular
    .module('myApp')
    .service('myService', myService)
    .controller('MyController', MyController);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyController as ctrl">
    {{ ctrl.result }}
  </div>
</div>
```